# push strings as items in ionic list using InfiniteScroll

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to make a list and when i come to bottom of my list , it should show some items . I am using `ion-infinite-scroll`directive .But i am not able to push the name (string) in my list. My list is just of names of all students in a classroom.
here is my code. can u please tell me how to push the strings in my list and how to call `complete()` method ?

**.html**

```
            <h2>{{item.name}}</h2> 
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadMore($scope)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content>
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

**.ts**

```
export class NotificationsPage {
i: number;
items: any = [];
name: any;
InfiniteScroll: any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let item = {
            name:i,
        };
        this.items.push(item);
    }

    this.InfiniteScroll.complete()


}
loadMore(InfiniteScroll: any) {
    this.objects.items.push({this.items});

};

ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad NotificationsPage');
};
```

}

Comment: what you want to do?  $scope looks horrible here. add some working code

Comment: i tried by taking references on net, but couldn't. plz help me with this. @SwapnilPatwa

Comment: Is this worked?

Comment: thanks a lot ..it worked..!   @SwapnilPatwa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this way- working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9dV3mc?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list *ngFor="let item of items">
        <h2>{{item?.name}}</h2>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadMore($event)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content>
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

TS:

```
import {  Component } from '@angular/core';
import {  NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    items: any = [];
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
    load() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            let item = {
                name: i,
            };
            this.items.push(item);
        }
    }
    loadMore(InfiniteScroll: any) {

        this.load();
        InfiniteScroll.complete();
    };

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.load();
    };
}
```